# jquery - dynamic content inside a html table not getting recognised by .innerHtml code (JS / JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, innerhtml

I have a HTML table in my web-application to which I allow my users to dynamically add rows using the `onclick` event.

However when I try to get the HTML contents of this table, (which is my objective) using either :

```
$("#table1").html()
```

or

```
var x = document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML;
```

I get only the initial table, and **not the rows that were added dynamically.** 
Interestingly in jQuery when I use

```
$("#nutritiontable ").text()
```

I get details of the dynamic rows also, but obviously not the html tags for which I have use. I want both.

Want to know if I missed something, or if anyone knows of any other way to get the entire HTML table with the dynamic content and with the html tags intact.

Comment: How are you adding the rows?

Comment: $(data1).insertBefore("table tbody #totalrow").effect("highlight", {
                    color: "#BCDDB7"
                }, 3E3);

Basically I find my last row (which does a total of all values) and I insert the new row before it.

Comment: why are you using `id` selecter `#totalrow` it can be multiple.

Comment: I'm using an id because I want my new rows to get added only above the one with the id #totalrow.

Comment: Please can you write `table` html here?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I would've given the code; but its a huge messed up code with a lot of inline css and scripting. Its too much of a mess to give out here. But framework wise its a standard table. It has a th, few tr's inside a table tag, to which i dynamically add tr's nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: It could be better that you post html so we can help you what is going wrong.

Comment: You can use `.insertAfter()`. Do `$('<tr><td>Row text</td></tr>').insertAfter("table tbody #totalrow")`

Answer (score 0):

If you add rows by

```
$("#table1").append("<tr><td>something</td></tr>")
```

Then

```
$("#table1").html()
```

Will give you everything.

Comment: Thanks Adi / Vlad. Will try your recommendation and get back.

Comment: I tried using .append but then, the new row gets added as the last row, which is below the row that gives a total.<br><br> I want the row to always be inserted as the 3rd last row to keep the logical flow of the information being provided. Hence I had to use insert and not append <br><br> $(data1).insertBefore("table tbody #totalrow")

Insert gives me better control over where the new row will get inserted.

Comment: Hmm... Could you maybe add the <br><br> after the table, instead of having the last row of the table serve this purpose? This way you can always append to the last of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function in jQuery.

```
$("#tableid").append('<tr><td>Row text</td></tr>');
```